# Studio 5000 - Add Rung Comment via Neutral Text

Tags: plc

I have to import alot of rungs into Studio 5000 given only the neutral text. But after that i have to manually add a rung comment to every rung. I am trying to add the rung comment to the neutral text before importing but i dont know if that is possible.

For example something like  ---> NOP();

should turn into --------------> //rung comment,NOP();

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no way to paste normal text directly into a rung with comments.

You can import a .L5X file that contains XML.

This should work as a bare minimum for importing rungs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<RSLogix5000Content ContainsContext="false" SchemaRevision="1.0" TargetType="Rung">
    <Rung>
        <Comment><![CDATA[TEST]]></Comment>
        <Text><![CDATA[NOP();]]></Text>
    </Rung>
</RSLogix5000Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different formats for importing/exporting in Studio 5000:

- L5K is an import/export format that contains entire projects only.
- L5X is an XML file format that can contain either an entire project or a portion of a project, such as individual rungs.
- CSV and TXT are two file formats that do not contain logic, but can contain both tags and logic comments for import/export.

Each of these file formats are different, and the method for encoding a rung comment is different in each.  Rockwell has a document called [Logix 5000 Controllers Import/Export](https://literature.rockwellautomation.com/idc/groups/literature/documents/rm/1756-rm084_-en-p.pdf) that explains everything in detail.  Alternatively, you can create a rung with a comment in your project, export it using your desired format, and then examine it to see where the rung comment goes in the file.